# Log4j Logger class loading blocks application threads

Tags: log4j, log4j2

Threads got BLOCKED when application threads heavily tried to log. Has this been encountered before. Does Async logger solve problems around this. Below is the thread dump indicating application threads getting BLOCKED when it was trying to heavily log exceptions. Multiple threads got into a BLOCKED state

```
"app[LARLAca][TG][T#7]" #55 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f2de800b800 nid=0x2fee runnable [0x00007f2e048ee000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntry(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntry(ZipFile.java:316)
    - locked <0x00007f2f5c2e1310> (a java.util.jar.JarFile)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getEntry(JarFile.java:240)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getJarEntry(JarFile.java:223)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:1054)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(URLClassPath.java:249)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419)
    - locked <0x00007f2f5e3c4d30> (a java.lang.Object)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:240)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ThrowableProxy.loadClass(ThrowableProxy.java:633)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ThrowableProxy.loadClass(ThrowableProxy.java:624)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ThrowableProxy.toExtendedStackTrace(ThrowableProxy.java:738)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:138)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:122)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jLogEvent.getThrownProxy(Log4jLogEvent.java:605)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.ExtendedThrowablePatternConverter.format(ExtendedThrowablePatternConverter.java:64)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.PatternFormatter.format(PatternFormatter.java:38)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout$PatternSerializer.toSerializable(PatternLayout.java:334)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.toText(PatternLayout.java:233)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.encode(PatternLayout.java:218)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.encode(PatternLayout.java:58)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.directEncodeEvent(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:177)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.tryAppend(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:170)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.append(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:161)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender.append(RollingFileAppender.java:309)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:156)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender0(AppenderControl.java:129)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppenderPreventRecursion(AppenderControl.java:120)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:84)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:464)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.processLogEvent(LoggerConfig.java:448)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:431)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:406)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.log(AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.java:63)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.logMessage(Logger.java:146)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.tryLogMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2170)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageTrackRecursion(AbstractLogger.java:2125)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageSafely(AbstractLogger.java:2108)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessage(AbstractLogger.java:1991)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:1835)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.warn(AbstractLogger.java:2684)
```

```
"app[LARLAca][TG][T#1]" #44 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f36fe6b3000 nid=0x2fe3 waiting for monitor entry [0x00007f2e06bfb000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:399)
    - waiting to lock <0x00007f2f5e3c4d30> (a java.lang.Object)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.LoaderUtil.loadClass(LoaderUtil.java:168)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ThrowableProxy.loadClass(ThrowableProxy.java:622)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ThrowableProxy.toExtendedStackTrace(ThrowableProxy.java:738)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:138)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:122)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jLogEvent.getThrownProxy(Log4jLogEvent.java:605)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.ExtendedThrowablePatternConverter.format(ExtendedThrowablePatternConverter.java:64)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.PatternFormatter.format(PatternFormatter.java:38)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout$PatternSerializer.toSerializable(PatternLayout.java:334)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.toText(PatternLayout.java:233)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.encode(PatternLayout.java:218)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.encode(PatternLayout.java:58)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.directEncodeEvent(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:177)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.tryAppend(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:170)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.append(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:161)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender.append(RollingFileAppender.java:309)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:156)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender0(AppenderControl.java:129)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppenderPreventRecursion(AppenderControl.java:120)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:84)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:464)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.processLogEvent(LoggerConfig.java:448)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:431)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:406)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.log(AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.java:63)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.logMessage(Logger.java:146)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.tryLogMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2170)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageTrackRecursion(AbstractLogger.java:2125)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageSafely(AbstractLogger.java:2108)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessage(AbstractLogger.java:1991)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:1835)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.warn(AbstractLogger.java:2684)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. using a `%ex` in the pattern layout prevent the `ThrowableProxy`  class loading thus saving the thread from getting BLOCKED